# main.CRITICAL: Exception message: CRLF injection detected Trace:

Tags: magento2.4.1

I'm eoncountering this issue on my Magento 2.4.1 website:

when trying to make an order, by some devices (like my smartphone) at the url https://mywebsite.com/checkout/#shipping the page remains loading (see image below), by others (like my notebook) it works properly, but when making a purchase I receive no order mail confirmation

[image: smartphone]

Magento logs show this errors,is there someone who can help me? Really thinks

```
[2023-05-31 11:22:03] main.CRITICAL: Exception message: CRLF injection detected
Trace: <pre>#1 Laminas\Mail\AddressList->createAddress('250477179@qq.com', '沙巴体育，...') called at [vendor/laminas/laminas-mail/src/AddressList.php:34]
#2 Laminas\Mail\AddressList->add('250477179@qq.com', '沙巴体育，...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessage.php:225]
#3 Magento\Framework\Mail\EmailMessage->convertAddressArrayToAddressList(array(&Magento\Framework\Mail\Address#0000000038ae3a730000000069f4b37d#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessage.php:75]
#4 Magento\Framework\Mail\EmailMessage->__construct(&Magento\Framework\Mail\MimeMessage#0000000038ae3a320000000069f4b37d#, array(&Magento\Framework\Mail\Address#0000000038ae3a730000000069f4b37d#), &Magento\Framework\Mail\MimeMessageInterfaceFactory#0000000038ae3e8f0000000069f4b37d#, &Magento\Framework\Mail\AddressFactory#0000000038ae3eb10000000069f4b37d#, array(&Magento\Framework\Mail\Address#0000000038ae3a4e0000000069f4b37d#), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Benvenuto a Euro...', 'utf-8') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/Mail/EmailMessage/Interceptor.php:14]
#5 Magento\Framework\Mail\EmailMessage\Interceptor->__construct(&Magento\Framework\Mail\MimeMessage#0000000038ae3a320000000069f4b37d#, array(&Magento\Framework\Mail\Address#0000000038ae3a730000000069f4b37d#), &Magento\Framework\Mail\MimeMessageInterfaceFactory#0000000038ae3e8f0000000069f4b37d#, &Magento\Framework\Mail\AddressFactory#0000000038ae3eb10000000069f4b37d#, array(&Magento\Framework\Mail\Address#0000000038ae3a4e0000000069f4b37d#), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Benvenuto a Euro...', 'utf-8') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121]
#6 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\Framewor...', array(&Magento\Framework\Mail\MimeMessage#0000000038ae3a320000000069f4b37d#, array(&Magento\Framework\Mail\Address#0000000038ae3a730000000069f4b37d#), &Magento\Framework\Mail\MimeMessageInterfaceFactory#0000000038ae3e8f0000000069f4b37d#, &Magento\Framework\Mail\AddressFactory#0000000038ae3eb10000000069f4b37d#, array(&Magento\Framework\Mail\Address#0000000038ae3a4e0000000069f4b37d#), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Benvenuto a Euro...', 'utf-8')) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:108]
#7 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\Framewor...', array('from' => array(&Magento\Framework\Mail\Address#0000000038ae3a4e0000000069f4b37d#), 'to' => array(&Magento\Framework\Mail\Address#0000000038ae3a730000000069f4b37d#), 'encoding' => 'utf-8', 'body' => &Magento\Framework\Mail\MimeMessage#0000000038ae3a320000000069f4b37d#, 'subject' => 'Benvenuto a Euro...')) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#8 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('\Magento\Framewo...', array('from' => array(&Magento\Framework\Mail\Address#0000000038ae3a4e0000000069f4b37d#), 'to' => array(&Magento\Framework\Mail\Address#0000000038ae3a730000000069f4b37d#), 'encoding' => 'utf-8', 'body' => &Magento\Framework\Mail\MimeMessage#0000000038ae3a320000000069f4b37d#, 'subject' => 'Benvenuto a Euro...')) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/Mail/EmailMessageInterfaceFactory.php:43]
#9 Magento\Framework\Mail\EmailMessageInterfaceFactory->create(array('from' => array(&Magento\Framework\Mail\Address#0000000038ae3a4e0000000069f4b37d#), 'to' => array(&Magento\Framework\Mail\Address#0000000038ae3a730000000069f4b37d#), 'encoding' => 'utf-8', 'body' => &Magento\Framework\Mail\MimeMessage#0000000038ae3a320000000069f4b37d#, 'subject' => 'Benvenuto a Euro...')) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php:414]
#10 Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder->prepareMessage() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php:336]
#11 Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder->getTransport() called at [vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/EmailNotification.php:275]
#12 Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification->sendEmailTemplate(&Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer#0000000038ae39e00000000069f4b37d#, 'customer/create_...', 'customer/create_...', array('customer' => &Magento\Customer\Model\Data\CustomerSecure#0000000038ae39db0000000069f4b37d#, 'back_url' => NULL, 'store' => &Magento\Store\Model\Store\Interceptor#0000000038ae3d4c0000000069f4b37d#), 1) called at [vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/EmailNotification.php:401]
#13 Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification->newAccount(&Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer#0000000038ae39e00000000069f4b37d#, 'registered', NULL, 1, NULL) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#14 Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification\Interceptor->___callParent('newAccount', array(&Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer#0000000038ae39e00000000069f4b37d#, 'registered', NULL, 1, NULL)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#15 Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer#0000000038ae39e00000000069f4b37d#, 'registered', NULL, 1, NULL) called at [vendor/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension/Plugin/CustomerEmailNotificationPlugin.php:64]
#16 Dotdigitalgroup\Email\Plugin\CustomerEmailNotificationPlugin->aroundNewAccount(&Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification\Interceptor#0000000038ae39bb0000000069f4b37d#, &Closure#0000000038ae39ba0000000069f4b37d#, &Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer#0000000038ae39e00000000069f4b37d#, 'registered', NULL, 1) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#17 Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer#0000000038ae39e00000000069f4b37d#, 'registered', NULL, 1) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#18 Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification\Interceptor->___callPlugins('newAccount', array(&Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer#0000000038ae39e00000000069f4b37d#, 'registered', NULL, 1), NULL) called at [generated/code/Magento/Customer/Model/EmailNotification/Interceptor.php:23]
#19 Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification\Interceptor->newAccount(&Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer#0000000038ae39e00000000069f4b37d#, 'registered', NULL, 1) called at [vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php:979]
#20 Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement->sendEmailConfirmation(&Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer#0000000038ae39e00000000069f4b37d#, NULL) called at [vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php:937]
#21 Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement->createAccountWithPasswordHash(&Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer#0000000038ae39e00000000069f4b37d#, 'e5a42ce0e03479f8...', NULL) called at [vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php:853]
#22 Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement->createAccount(&Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer#0000000038ae38cd0000000069f4b37d#, 'DZcs@xsq64241155...', NULL) called at [vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php:380]
#23 Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#24 Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor->___callParent('execute', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#25 Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Plugin/Account.php:64]
#26 Magento\Customer\Controller\Plugin\Account->aroundExecute(&Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor#0000000038ae3f510000000069f4b37d#, &Closure#0000000038ae3f490000000069f4b37d#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#27 Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Plugin/ActionFlagNoDispatchPlugin.php:51]
#28 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Plugin\ActionFlagNoDispatchPlugin->aroundExecute(&Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor#0000000038ae3f510000000069f4b37d#, &Closure#0000000038ae3f490000000069f4b37d#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#29 Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#30 Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor->___callPlugins('execute', array(), array(array('customer-app-act...'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost/Interceptor.php:23]
#31 Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:111]
#32 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000038ae3c070000000069f4b37d#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#33 Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000038ae3c070000000069f4b37d#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#34 Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000038ae3c070000000069f4b37d#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#35 Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000038ae3c070000000069f4b37d#), array(array('catalog_app_acti...', 'contextPlugin'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost/Interceptor.php:32]
#36 Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000038ae3c070000000069f4b37d#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:186]
#37 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000038ae3c070000000069f4b37d#, &Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor#0000000038ae3f510000000069f4b37d#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:118]
#38 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000038ae3c070000000069f4b37d#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#39 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000038ae3c070000000069f4b37d#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#40 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000038ae3c070000000069f4b37d#) called at [vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php:99]
#41 Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor#0000000038ae3d720000000069f4b37d#, &Closure#0000000038ae3d6e0000000069f4b37d#, &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000038ae3c070000000069f4b37d#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#42 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000038ae3c070000000069f4b37d#) called at [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:75]
#43 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor#0000000038ae3d720000000069f4b37d#, &Closure#0000000038ae3d6e0000000069f4b37d#, &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000038ae3c070000000069f4b37d#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#44 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000038ae3c070000000069f4b37d#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#45 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000038ae3c070000000069f4b37d#), NULL) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:23]
#46 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000038ae3c070000000069f4b37d#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#47 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:23]
#48 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:263]
#49 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#0000000038ae3cdc0000000069f4b37d#) called at [index.php:39]
</pre> [] []
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error appears entering the checkout page, without entering any data yet, I don't think this loading problem is related with your exception log message.

---

**Checkout error**

The checkout error might be caused by a third party module.

Try again after disabling third party modules or custom modules called on this page in order to find out which one is generating the loading problem (eg. : the Amazon pay module).

---

**Exception log error**

About the error showing in the exception log, it's triggered by a security preventing customers to enter unauthorized data in the customer fields, and prevent them from sending spam email from your website.
We can see the content of the name field is containing chinese data, which is probably an attempt to send a spam to a list of email.

This technique is generaly executed by bots, which target website without captcha (or low security captcha).

You should at least activate the native Magento captcha, but I recommend you to use a more powerful one such as the Google reCaptcha.

Comment: Hello, first of all thanks. Disabling Amazon Pay module solved the issue. Although, I don't receive order confirmation email. Do you think is it a related issue? I've just made an order by my smartphone (before disabling Amazon Pay it was not possible to conclude the purchase) and I receive no confirmation email

Comment: I tried to send an email directly from the order and it doesn't work anyway. Further I changed the sender email address but it doesn't work at the same way. Do you have any suggest? Really thanks